# How to adjust the default memory size ratio of the JVM

Tags: java, jvm

How can we not set the memory size of the JVM through - xmx128m - xms64m, and the default memory size of jdk8 is 1 / 4 of the physical machine memory, how can we change the value of 1 / 4, for example, to 1 / 2

Comment: `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50`

Comment: ^ What @apanging said. There's also `MaxRAMFraction` that is less flexible. https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk11.html says the options were introduced in JDK 10 but there's a backport since java 8u191: https://merikan.com/2019/04/jvm-in-a-container/

Comment: That's exactly what we need, thank you very much！